# Undefined username in cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to send a notification to a specific device so I write this function and its work right but I got undefined in the username

Logs output:

Get this

```
after: { '-LhjfwZeu0Ryr6jYRq5r': { Price: '888', date: '2019-6-19', description: 'Ghh', id: 50, nameOfProblem: 'Vbh', providerName: 'Loy', providerService: 'Carpenter', statusInfo: 'Incomplete', time: '15:22', username:"devas" }}
```

And the `username` is `undefined`

Here is the function

```
exports.sendPushR = functions.database.ref('/request/{pid}/{uid}/orders')
    .onWrite(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const registrationTokens = "------";
        const providerId = context.params.pid;
        const userId = context.params.uid;
        const event = context.params;
        console.log("event", event);
        console.log(`New Order from ${userId} to ${providerId}`);
        const afterData = snapshot.after.val(); // data after the write
        const username = snapshot.after.val().username;
        console.log(afterData);
        console.log(username);
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Message received',
                body: `You received a new order from ${username} check it now! `,
                sound: "default",
                icon: "default",
            }
        };


        try {
            const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload);
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        }
        return null;
    });
```

Comment: from the data you shared it looks like username is a level deeper than you are retrieving

Comment: @FunKeyFlo  Hmm, so how to access them because the parent is a generated key from real-time DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code you wrote is meant to run when a new order is added to the database. But you've declared it to trigger like this:

```
exports.sendPushR = functions.database.ref('/request/{pid}/{uid}/orders')
    .onWrite(async (snapshot, context) => {
```

This means that the code instead triggers whenever anything is written under the `orders` node for a user. To trigger only when an order is written under that `orders` node, define your trigger as:

```
exports.sendPushR = functions.database.ref('/request/{pid}/{uid}/orders/{orderid}')
    .onWrite(async (snapshot, context) => {
```

The difference above is that the path now includes `{orderid}` meaning that it triggers one level lower in the tree, and your `snapshot.after` will no longer contain the `-L` level.

---

Since you actually only seem to care about when an order gets created, you can also only trigger on that (meaning your function won't get called when an order gets updated or deleted). That'd be something like this:

```
exports.sendPushR = functions.database.ref('/request/{pid}/{uid}/orders/{orderid}')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    ...
    const afterData = snapshot.val();
    const username = snapshot.val().username;
    console.log(afterData);
    console.log(username);
    ...
});
```

Here we again trigger on the lower-level in the JSON. But since we now trigger `onCreate`, we no longer have a before and after snapshot, and instead just do `snapshot.val()` to get the data that was just created.

Comment: Thank you, Frank, Now if we want to define "{orderid},{uid},{pid}" in deep, What we say?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean there. Can you elaborate or explain in other words?

Comment: I mean the `{orderid}` in the path, meaning trigger or what in firebase and how it know it's orderid not userid for example?

Comment: The `{orderid}` is just a declaration of what name to use for that path segment. You could call it `{whatever}` and it'd work the same as long as you call it `whatever` everywhere else too.

Answer (score 0):

Since the object you are retrieving has a generated member you could use a for-in loop to retrieve the value.

```
const object = snapshot.after.val()
for(const key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const element = object[key];
        if(element.username) {
             console.log(element.username);
             break;
        }  
    }
}
```